# Interpreting tick by tick stock data

Tags: market-data, tick-data

I downloaded data regarding the YUM stock traded on the New York Stock Exchange in the year 2014. Basically in this dataset, we have 4 columns: the first column is the day the second column is the time in milliseconds expressed in epoch time,  the third column is the transaction price and the fourth column is the volume.
At a particular moment, there are instances where transactions, reported in milliseconds, occur at the same price and instant but involve different volumes
for example

```
28,1393603190476,56940,450
28,1393603190476,56940,188
```

These 2 rows indicate that on the 28th at the instant 1393603190476(milliseconds elapsed from 1 January 1970) there are 2 transactions at the same price with different volume
Why are the transactions reported separately if they occur at the same instant?

Comment: Why not? At that moment Person A bought 638 shares, of which 450 were sold by person B and 188 by person C. That is how a Matching Engine works.

Comment: sorry if my question is stupid , but it is the first time I deal with real data : in this case we have ```28,1393603143937,56920,400
28,1393603143937,56920,1004
28,1393603143937,56910,600
28,1393603143937,56910,100
28,1393603143937,56910,100
28,1393603143937,56910,100
28,1393603143937,56910,100
28,1393603143937,56900,100
28,1393603143937,56900,800 ```   why in this case the transaction prices are different at the same instant? I had thought about selling and buying prices but there are 3 different prices at the same instant

Comment: I suggest you get some documentation from the source of the data. Guessing can only get us so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are the transactions reported separately if they occur at the same instant?

In the absence of any other information about your data source, it is most likely that **the trades do not occur at the same instant**. That is, your data source has timestamped the trades to the nearest milisecond. But trades on NYSE Arca are not executed in milisecond time buckets. There are trades within those miliseconds, and that is why it appears to you that they were executed at the same time. You can check the [real-time datafeed specification](https://www.nyse.com/publicdocs/nyse/data/NYSE_Pillar_Trades_Client_Specification.pdf), to see that the **trade message timestamps** go down to **nanoseconds**.

Regarding the importance of time resolution, I recall a paper that compares the differences between measurements derived from second vs. milisecond time-stamped TAQ data, definitely a good read:

Holden, Craig W., and Stacey Jacobsen. "Liquidity measurement problems in fast, competitive markets: Expensive and cheap solutions." The Journal of Finance 69, no. 4 (2014): 1747-1785.

Comment: is correct, they most likely did not occur in the same instant. It's just that your data source truncated the nanosecond part of the timestamp. That said, there are times when trades happen within the same nanosecond timestamp and sequence number; some matching engines are capable of reporting multiple events that are related to the same trade event.